# Spark on yarn, Connection reset by peer

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-shell

Searched a lot but all in vain, this is a 3 node EC2 cluster in AWS, checked the disk space, resources, running services, all seems to be fine but i get this error. Please help to resolve this.

10.0.1.5 & 10.0.1.6 are datanodes, i just ran the spark-shell from namenode.

Minimal configurations are edited, if needed i can post those here too.

```
$ spark-shell 
19/08/05 10:40:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
19/08/05 10:40:31 WARN yarn.Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
19/08/05 10:40:42 WARN server.TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.0.1.6:55202
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1106)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/08/05 10:40:42 ERROR client.TransportClient: Failed to send RPC RPC 6351187948645779511 to /10.0.1.5:44418: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source)
19/08/05 10:40:42 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to get executor loss reason for executor id 2 at RPC address 10.0.1.5:44428, but got no response. Marking as slave lost.
java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC RPC 6351187948645779511 to /10.0.1.5:44418: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$RpcChannelListener.handleFailure(TransportClient.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$StdChannelListener.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:334)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetFailure(AbstractChannel.java:987)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:869)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1316)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1081)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1128)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1070)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```